# watermark on videos like tiktok watermark using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

I want to add watermark on video using ffmpeg like tiktok videos, means watermark with logo name and user id and with reflecting diagonally each 5 sec or same interval of time, for simple watermark I am using following command.Please help

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=5:5" out.mp4`

Comment: _"...With reflecting diagonally each 5 sec"_ what does this even mean? Provide a link to a video example of this thing you want to achieve. If it's animated, might be easier to create a GIF first then use it as (looping) watermark

Comment: use `overlay='5*mod(n,150)':'3*mod(n,150)'` where `n` is number of frame, `150` is `5sec * 30fps`, play with numbers

Comment: @VC.One please see this video link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=in46zjhGyk0
for watermark and if possible give me better suggestions, how can I implement ?

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов thank you for your suggestion but  I required https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=in46zjhGyk0 watermark like this

Comment: maybe this: `overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,6),3),W-w-W*10/100,W*10/100)':
y='if(lt(mod(t+12,6),3),H-h-H*5/100,H*5/100)'`?

Answer (score 6):

**Top-Left To Bottom-Right loop:**

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
 "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,W-w-10)':y='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,H-h-10)'" \
 -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

**Top-Right To Bottom-Left loop:**

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
 "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),W-w-10,10)':y='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,H-h-10)'" \ 
 -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

Idea is very simple

- Take every 10sec duration, get remainder sec i.e. mod(t,10)
- if sec < 5,  set top position else bottom position

Comment: I noticed you did not include text. How can this be done to include username as well?

Comment: Also anyway to combine these 2 commands so it's TL, BR, TR, BL and loops all 4 corners?