# FFmpeg - shift logo overlay along the video corners

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been able to adapt some of the examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072634/watermark-on-videos-like-tiktok-watermark-using-ffmpeg) I've found to make the logos shift like TikTok but they only do certain corners. How do you combine these 2 commands into one so that it rotates the logo like Top-Left, Bottom-Right, Top-Right, Bottom-Left and loop until the end of the video? It should work with any resolution like 16:9 or 9:16 etc.

This does Top-Left to Bottom-Right

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
 "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,W-w-10)':y='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,H-h-10)'" \
 -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

This does Top-Right To Bottom-Left

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
 "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),W-w-10,10)':y='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,H-h-10)'" \ 
 -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

Now how do you combine them into one  and loop.

In addition to combining this, can a text (drawtext) be added under the moving logo as well for a username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`overlay=x='W/2-pow(-1,lt(mod(t,20),10))*((W-w)/2-10)-w/2':y='H/2-pow(-1,lt(mod(t,10),5))*((H-h)/2-10)-h/2'`

This will cycle through `Top-Left, Bottom-Right, Top-Right, Bottom-Left`. Change the sign in front of `pow` to reverse direction.

Comment: Thanks it does combine them and works. Can I ask how could you add text underneath the logo that rotates with it?

Comment: Make a new image with the logo on top and text at bottom and use that as overlay input.

Comment: So you're saying I have to create a new image from the logo with the text on it, is the best way to add text?

Comment: If you want to move the text in sync with the logo, yes.